# Android: ClassCastException TextView cannot be converted to CalendarView

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have a problem with a custom made calendarview. I have the following xml-file called calendar.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_month_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/prev_month_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Previous" />

<no.blopp.app.views.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/next_month_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/month_of_year_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/prev_month_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/prev_month_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="September 2012"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to get CalendarView in the activity, I get a classcastexception. Here is the Java code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarview);
    calendarView.setOnCellTouchListener(this);
    }
```

(I have declared "private CalendarView calendarView" on top of the code, but something weird happened with the viewing of the codeblock when I tried to copy it in. I'm a newbie, so sorry about that).
The classcast exception is thrown at:

```
calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Are there any problems in my xml-file?

Comment: post CalendarView.java and fullstacktrace

Comment: remember this "import no.blopp.app.views.CalendarView"?

Answer (score 0):

you could try declaring a namespace for your custom component in the XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mycomponent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/replaceWithStringFromPackageAttributeInManifest.xml"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

...

<mycomponent:no.blopp.app.views.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/next_month_button" />

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You don't see the answer because it was deleted but a correct answer was provided to the question: *remove "gen" folder in your project.. then run again..*